# How can I use Linq to to determine if this string EndsWith a value (from a collection)?

Tags: .net, linq-to-objects

i'm trying to find out if a string value `EndsWith` another string. This 'other string' are the values from a collection. I'm trying to do this as an extension method, for strings.

eg.

```
var collection = string[] { "ny", "er", "ty" };
"Johnny".EndsWith(collection); // returns true.
"Fred".EndsWith(collection); // returns false.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var collection = new string[] { "ny", "er", "ty" };

var doesEnd = collection.Any("Johnny".EndsWith);
var doesNotEnd = collection.Any("Fred".EndsWith);
```

You can create a String extension to hide the usage of `Any`

```
public static bool EndsWith(this string value, params string[] values)
{
    return values.Any(value.EndsWith);
}

var isValid = "Johnny".EndsWith("ny", "er", "ty");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to the .NET framework but here is an extension method that will do the trick:

```
public static Boolean EndsWith(this String source, IEnumerable<String> suffixes)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source)) return false;
    if (suffixes == null) return false;

    foreach (String suffix in suffixes)
        if (source.EndsWith(suffix))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Cheers andrew. yeah, this is (more or less) what i've already got. I was wanting to see how to do this as Linq (so I can learn it).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Ex{
 public static bool EndsWith(this string item, IEnumerable<string> list){
   foreach(string s in list) {
    if(item.EndsWith(s) return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
}
```